# Django seperating apps?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am working on a Learning Management System. At this moment I want to make a calendar app that will display a calendar and show "events". These events can either be a project or a training program. But I am not sure what would be the best design choice in terms of seperating the apps. Should I add the models for projects and trainings in my calendar app or should these two be seperated apps that I can connect to an Event model in the calendar app?